# Why can't I see this documentation proposed change in review?

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues, documentation-proposals

#### Situation:

So I've been going through the reviews for today, and I cannot help myself getting really annoyed by this 1 proposal that has been here for at least an hour, and isn't visible for me:

[image]

But whenever I click on it, it shows me this:

[image]

Are there any documentation subjects I cannot view? Do I need at least `x` rep in a certain tag for it to be visible? I'm aware sometimes reviews get resolved in the time you open the review overview page and when you select a type, but this has been here for *at least an hour*.

#### Update a day later:

[image]

Still having this issue with mixed amounts of proposed changes, still can't view them. The amount fluctuates between 1-3.

Comment: I've had this happen to me, too, and I'm not entirely sure what causes it. You can still review it; you just need a direct link to it.

Comment: I don't know why it does that, but you can click on the history tab and if someone else has already reviewed it, you can click on the link to the review and then review it.